# Python Selenium: Selecting from a list by text

Tags: python, selenium, syntax

I have spent the past few days trying to solve this problem. I store a string in a variable and i am trying to automate using selenium to select the item whose text()='string stored in the variable'.

I noticed i could not select some of the items in the list even though the text was exactly the same as the string i stored in the variable. The i realized today that some of the texts have a space before the next item. For example;
instead of (Architecture)
it says (Architecture )

This is the code i was running;

```
fc = 'COMMUNICATION'
faculty = WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="agentApplicationForm'
                                                                                '"]/div/div[9]/div['
                                                                                '1]/div/span/span/span[1]')))
print(faculty.is_displayed())
faculty.click()
sleep(5)

faculty_select = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'//*[@id="Program1FacultyInstitute_listbox"]/li[text().StartsWith("{fc}")]')
faculty_select.click()
sleep(2)
```

I am now trying to use text().startsWith({fc}) but i don't think i am using a correct syntax.

This is the error i get;

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //*[@id="Program1FacultyInstitute_listbox"]/li[text().startsWith("COMMUNICATION")] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//*[@id="Program1FacultyInstitute_listbox"]/li[text().startsWith("COMMUNICATION")]' is not a valid XPath expression.
  (Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.96)
```

Can someone help me please.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to search text starting with:-

```
//*[@id="Program1FacultyInstitute_listbox"]/li[starts-with(text(),'fc')]
```

Or maybe try using contains to do substring match like below. But you will need to pass more accurate text to search in order to avoid multiple matches.

```
//*[@id="Program1FacultyInstitute_listbox"]/li[contains(text(),'fc')]
```

Comment: i have a new problem, when i successfully click on Architecture(faculty), it displays another dropdown to select a department and it has 1. Architecture* 2. Architecture (one ends with an asterisk which indicates it is a Turkish course and the other ends with a space). How do i use ({fc}.endsWith(' ')) so that i select the one that ends with a space? Thank you

Comment: For XPATH2.0, try this [starts-with(text(),'StartingText') and ends-with(text(),'Ending Text')]

Comment: You can also use below approach which will work with XPATH 1.0 as well: //*[starts-with(text(), 'Starting Text') and substring(text(), string-length(text()) - 1 + 1) = 't']          This is to match the last 1 character of the string. If you want to match last two or more characters, you can change the -1 to -2, -3 etc. like this     :     //*[starts-with(text(), 'Starting Text') and substring(text(), string-length(text()) - n + 1) = 'n length text']

Comment: Above example is given to match both starting and ending text. If you just need to search for ending text, use only this: substring(text(), string-length(text()) - n + 1) = 'n length text'

Comment: Thank you, i will try this out and let you know how it goes :)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to select only (one) element based on (text)

you can use

**faculty.click()**

**faculty.send_keys("value you want to select")**

notice that this method works only if you want to select only one value based on string , also it works in droplist.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).